# Calling a .jar file using laravel Framework for PHP

Tags: java, php, laravel

I have to run an .jar using an json file like argument and return another json, I use this methods:

```
exec("java -jar /grupa3/IP.jar /grupa3/input.json");
```

and another method that i try is using shell

```
shel_exec("java -jar /grupa3/IP.jar /grupa3/input.json");
```

but something is going wrong.
please someone help me.

I solve this problem with run .jar file but now i have another problem i need to execute another jar with an argument and it's don't work.
this is the code of running an jar without an argument and it's work:

```
<button id="execBTN" type="button"  onclick="executeJAR()" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Executa</button>
```

function in js:

```
var executeJAR = function () {

$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:81/Back-End/laravel/public/modul2",
    data: {execJAR: "true"}
}).done(function(){

});
```

}

and finally the php code:

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['execJAR'])){
        chdir('C:\wamp\www\Back-End\laravel\public\grupa2');
        exec('java -jar modul2.jar');
    } ?>
```

i use the same comand but with an argument:

```
exec('java -jar modul3.jar input.json');
```

and this comand don't work

Comment: Please document the behavior/error messages of the two calls.

Comment: just nothing happens. how i must call this jar right? i put this php code between button tag:

Comment: <div id="execut-mod-2" class="col-md-12">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Executa
                <?php
                    exec("java -jar /grupa3/IP.jar /grupa3/input.json");
                ?>
            </button>

Comment: Can you print the output of the two commands ?

Comment: First try to run the command from the **Command Prompt**. If you are not able to run there, then check whether the path of JAVA is in CLASS_PATH or not.  If it runs but with errors, then let us know that first. 1. Try this adding in Simple PHP Script, without the Laravel Framework and check if it's working or not 2. If still you are not getting any error, then while running the PHP Script, use the STRACE method attaching the PID of Apache - Refer: [Troubleshoot Using Strace](http://www.hokstad.com/5-simple-ways-to-troubleshoot-using-strace)

Comment: @VinodTigadi I try to run this comand in cmd and it's work. i try to do this with a PHP function and a onclick and without somme resultat or errors.

Comment: `shel_exec` is no valid command - but there **is** [shell_exec](https://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)

Comment: also : trying to call serverside (!) PHP functions within a website via HTML onclick-handler is just ... pure nonsense. You obviously dont even know how all of this works, what a "server" and a "client" is, what HTTP is and so on - i recommend doing a course about basic IT first, you will never be able to create something without basic IT knowledge.

Comment: someone can help me wih executing an .jar with an argument from php